# How to display data of an ArrayList using useBean; no JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, usebean

My servlet is building an ArrayList of a specific class (or a null ArrayList) and then setting it as an attribute in request and then forward to a JSP. In the JSP I am displaying the contents of that ArrayList using scriptlet.

Now in the JSP I want to display the contents of that ArrayList using useBean technology. Is it possible? ***I already know how to do it using JSTL technology***. But this question is about using only useBean technology i.e. no JSTL and of course no scriptlet.

This is my class **TestClass**:

```
public class TestClass implements Serializable {
   private int id;
   private String description;
   public int getId() { return this.id; }
   public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }
   public String getDescription() { return this.description; }
   public void setDescription(String description) { this.description = description; }
}
```

This is how I populate the ArrayList in my Servlet **TestClassServlet**:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
   List<TestClass> testClassList = null;
   TestClass testClass = null;
   String criteria = request.getParameter("criteria");

   if (criteria == null || criteria.trim().isEmpty()) {
      request.setAttribute("result", testClassList);

   } else if (criteria.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("ALL")) {
      testClassList = new ArrayList<TestClass>();
      testClass = new TestClass();
      testClass.setId(1);
      testClass.setDescription("Normal");
      testClassList.add(testClass);
      testClass = new TestClass();
      testClass.setId(2);
      testClass.setDescription("Priority");
      testClassList.add(testClass);
      request.setAttribute("result", testClassList);

   } else {
      request.setAttribute("result", testClassList);

   }

   request.getRequestDispatcher("test.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

This is how I am displaying it in JSP through scriptlet:

```
<%
List<TestClass> testClassList = (List<TestClass>) request.getAttribute("result");
if (testClassList == null) {
%>
    <select id="select_testClassList" disabled="disabled">
    </select>
<%  
} else {
%>
    <select id="select_testClassList">
        <option value=""></option>
<%  
    for (TestClass testClass : testClassList) {
%>
        <option value="<%=testClass.getId()%>"><%=testClass.getDescription()%></option>
<%      
    }
%>
    </select>
<%
}
%>
```

I first tried the useBean with the class as java.util.List

```
<jsp:useBean id="testClassList" class="java.util.List" scope="request"></jsp:useBean>
```

But it did not even compile as I got this error message:

> Cannot instantiate the type List

Fair enough as per specs of useBean technology. I change it to java.util.ArrayList with generics:

```
<jsp:useBean id="testClassList" class="java.util.ArrayList<TestClass>" scope="request"></jsp:useBean>
```

But then I got this error message:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /test2.jsp(14,0) The value for the
>   useBean class attribute java.util.ArrayList is invalid.

I then change it to java.util.ArrayList without generics:

```
<jsp:useBean id="testClassList" class="java.util.ArrayList" scope="request"></jsp:useBean>
```

After that I dont get any error.

Now I dont know how to loop through the ArrayList using useBean technology. I think I have to use `jsp:getProperty` but that will work on object of TestClass and my concern is how to get object of TestClass from the ArrayList?

Thanks